# How to convert a String into Unsigned Long. With a twist

Tags: c++, string

Hello
I have a string parser who receives as its input a hex number:
For Example:
String X="0x120005f38"

As you can see the number is in HEX, how do I convert this to unsigned long?

If this was decimal based string I could use the string to unsigned long function.
I am guessing there are a couple of steps, and I am not sure what order or functions to use. 
1)Where I need to convert Hex into decimal
2)and String into unsigned long.

This seems very tricky to me, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `strtoul`:

```
strtoul("0x120005f3", 0, 0);
```

`strtoul` reference on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/). See how that works on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/jG5g93BM).

**EDIT:** Changed to `strtoul`, did not notice that `unsigned long` is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `base` parameter of the [`strtoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/) function, which allows a `0x` prefix on the string.

Answer (score 1):

Using streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    const char* X="0x120005f38";
    std::stringstream ss(X);
    long long var;  //your value is too large for my long
    ss >> std::hex >> var;
    std::cout << var << ' ' << std::hex << var << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is literally your code, just don't make it a literal integer with 0x prefix: `int x = 0x120005f38;`